# How to Quit Browser in WDS in JMeter and stop execution

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, jmeter

i am trying to Quit the browser in Selenium Jmeter last sampler of my thread but it consistently giving me error saying

```
INFO c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: WebDriver has been quit.
2024-02-01 22:53:24,989 ERROR c.g.j.p.w.s.WebDriverSampler: Session ID is null. Using WebDriver after calling quit()?
Build info: version: '4.10.0', revision: 'c14d967899'
```

i tried multiple things to close like

```
WDS.browser.quit()
and
WDS.browser.Close()
```

here's my code

```
 var handles = WDS.browser.getWindowHandles().toArray();
            WDS.browser.switchTo().window(handles[handles.length - 1]);
            java.lang.Thread.sleep(3000);
            WDS.browser.close();
            WDS.log.info("(ACO Dashboard Visit 360 Map) Page load correctly.");
        }

    } else {
        WDS.log.info("The Trimmed text does not contain ' Visit 360'. Skipping click.");
    }
} catch (err) {
    WDS.log.error("Error: " + err);
} finally {
    WDS.browser.quit();
    WDS.log.info("WebDriver has been quit.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do it.

[WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) starts the WebDriver instance when the thread (virtual user) is started and stops it and quits the browser when the virtual user is shut down **automatically**

If you want to have the full control you will have to switch to [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy).